# Manually define clusters in Seurat and determine marker genes

Tags: r, single-cell, seurat

I want to define two clusters of cells in my dataset and find marker genes that are specific to one and the other. Is there a way to do this in `Seurat`? Say, if I produce two subsets by the `SubsetData` function, is there a way to feed them into some other function that would calculate marker genes? If not, what other packages would you recommend for doing that?

If you look here:

https://satijalab.org/seurat/seurat_clustering_tutorial_part2.html

I just need a way to define `ident` myself, the number of levels (2) and assign numbers to each cell (0, 1), and then run `DE` between `0` and `1` clusters which is obvious how to do afterwards.

Comment: A related issue was answered on [github](https://github.com/satijalab/seurat/issues/285). Just as an alternative reference to the excellent answers below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking to `FindAllMarkers` function from `Seurat`. As you said, you just have to define your `ident`, that have to have the structure of a table (cell names as names and cluster as value):

```
pident=as.factor(clusters)
names(pident)=cellNames    
object1@ident=pident
```

And then run the `FindAllMarkers` function:

```
FindAllMarkers(object1, min.pct = 0.25, min.diff.pct = 0.25)
```

You can specify several parameters in this function (type of DE to perform, thresholds of expression, etc).

Answer (score 3):

Seurat has functions for adding metadata and setting identities. Get unique cell names:

```
cell.labels <- seuratobject@ident
```

Replace column and its name with your cluster labels ([e.g.](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/4303/208)), then:

```
seuratobject <- AddMetaData(seuratobject, metadata=cell.labels)
seuratobject <- SetAllIdent(seuratobject, id='yourclusterlabels')
```

Because you want to contrast two clusters against each other, I suggest using `FindMarkers()` as opposed to `FindAllMarkers()`:

```
FindMarkers(object, ident.1, ident.2)
```

It can also compare combinations of clusters.